# Key as Integer and Value as IntegerArray

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have the following HashMap:-

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer[]> possibleSeq = new HashMap<Integer,Integer[] >();
```

I would like to add into the map something like this:-

```
 possibleSeq.put(1,{1,2,3,4});
```

There are a large number of entries and i am supposed to enter manually:-
I tried doing this:-

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer aArr = {1,2,3,4};
  possibleSeq.put(a,aArr);
```

But this is not my requirement.I dont want to create separate Integer variables to store keys and separate Integer Arrays to store my values ie IntegerArray .Any Ideas??

Comment: Why `Integer[]`? I'm pretty sure you need `int[]`.

Comment: Generics don't work on primitives I think

Comment: int[] is an array, which is an object, so it's OK.  Just tried it, works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
public static void put(Map<Integer, Integer[]> map, Integer k, Integer... v) {
    map.put(k, v);
}

...

put(map, 1, 1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: +1, I like this, quite neat. You could even extend `Map` to create a more "native" looking api.

Comment: And you can go further with a builder that has `map` as a field and can return `this` for chaining.

Comment: And while on the subject of builders, by all means provide a factory method with a short name, which you can `import static`. That brings conciseness to the peak, without hurting readability a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can `new` the `Integer[]` inline:

```
possibleSeq.put(1, new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
```

Comment: Oh Yes!! ...My bad!! ...+1 for the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

```
possibleSeq.put(1,{1,2,3,4});
```

This is not valid Java syntax. Try this instead:

```
possibleSeq.put(1, new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
```

Answer (score 0):

`{1,2,3,4,5,6}` is not an array `new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5}` is an array of integers.

```
 possibleSeq.put(1,new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
```